# Write output to console from helper class

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-artisan

I have a console command that runs a helper class and I want to write output with `$this->info()` to the console from the helper class.

My code looks like this:

`App/Http/Console/Commands/SomeCommand.php`

```
function handle(Helper $helper)
{
    return $helper->somefunction();
}
```

`App/Http/SomeHelper.php`

```
function somefunction()
{
    //some code
    $this->info('send to console');
}
```

Is there any way to write the output to console from the helper?

Comment: Maybe if you extend Illuminate\Console\Command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### I finally figured this out (works in Laravel 5.6)

In the `handle()` function of your **SomeCommand** class, add `$this->myHelper->setConsoleOutput($this->getOutput());`.

In your helper class, add:

```
/**
 *
 * @var \Symfony\Component\Console\Style\OutputStyle 
 */
protected $consoleOutput;

/**
 * 
 * @param \Symfony\Component\Console\Style\OutputStyle $consoleOutput
 * @return $this
 */
public function setConsoleOutput($consoleOutput) {
    $this->consoleOutput = $consoleOutput;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param string $text
 * @return $this
 */
public function writeToOuput($text) {
    if ($this->consoleOutput) {
        $this->consoleOutput->writeln($text);
    }
    return $this;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param string $text
 * @return $this
 */
public function writeErrorToOuput($text) {
    if ($this->consoleOutput) {
        $style = new \Symfony\Component\Console\Formatter\OutputFormatterStyle('white', 'red', ['bold']); //white text on red background
        $this->consoleOutput->getFormatter()->setStyle('error', $style);
        $this->consoleOutput->writeln('<error>' . $text . '</error>');
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Then, anywhere else in your helper class, you can use:

```
$this->writeToOuput('Here is a string that I want to show in the console.');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to write `$this->info('send to console');` this in SomeCommand.php file.For writing output follow this https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/artisan#writing-output

Comment: I know it works there, but I need to output from the helper too.

Comment: @Alex try create a instance of SomeCommand and and then use that object instead of $this

Answer (score -3):

I have not tried, but maybe: `$this->line("sent to console');`