# Coloured Output To Console Outside Commands in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

inside Command i can output

```
$this->error();
$this->info();
```

but if i instantiate other classes inside Command - how do i make coloured output to console inside that external classes? That other classes does not extend Command class.

I have found only this solution, and i don't like it :)

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class External
{
    /** @var Command */
    protected $command;

    public function __construct(Command $command) {
        $this->command = $command;
    }

    protected function error($msg)
    {
        $this->command->error($msg);
    }

    protected function info($msg, $v = null)
    {
        $this->command->info($msg, $v);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean, "you don't like it"? Does it work? If so, then what's the issue?

Comment: @maiorano84, too much work. durty solution. i instantiate 10 classes from the command - and i have to inject Command to all of them and all logging functions as well.

Comment: @maiorano84, and this is just two log levels here - there are more of them! and each one should have extra method in all of that classes.

Answer (score 10):

Your existing approach seems pretty reasonable.

You could use [this approach](http://blog.lenss.nl/2012/05/adding-colors-to-php-cli-script-output/) which is lighter.

```
  /*
    Black 0;30
    Blue 0;34
    Green 0;32
    Cyan 0;36
    Red 0;31
    Purple 0;35
    Brown 0;33
    Light Gray 0;37 
    Dark Gray 1;30
    Light Blue 1;34
    Light Green 1;32
    Light Cyan 1;36
    Light Red 1;31
    Light Purple 1;35
    Yellow 1;33
    White 1;37
  */

  echo "\033[31m some colored text \033[0m some white text \n";
  echo "\033[32m some colored text \033[0m some white text \n";
```

You also have access to the underlying SymfonyCommand so in your existing approach you could [do this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/console/coloring.html).

```
  <?php

  use Illuminate\Console\Command;
  use Symfony\Component\Console\Formatter\OutputFormatterStyle;

  class External
  {
      /** @var Command */
      protected $command;

      public function __construct(Command $command) {
          $this->command = $command;
      }

      protected function error($msg)
      {
          $this->command->error($msg);
      }

      protected function info($msg, $v = null)
      {
          $this->command->info($msg, $v);
      }
      protected function fire($msg)
      {
          // Custom colors
          $style = new OutputFormatterStyle('red', 'yellow', array('bold', 'blink'));
          $this->command->output->getFormatter()->setStyle('fire', $style);

          $this->command->output->writeln('<fire>' . msg . '</fire>');
      }
  }
```

Comment: That's cool. Thanks. I just used it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52264295/470749

Answer (score 5):

First approach is implemented in [nunomaduro / collision](https://github.com/nunomaduro/collision) package:

```
<?php

$color = new NunoMaduro\Collision\ConsoleColor;

echo($color->apply("red", "some text in red"));
```

Comment: Just used this to add a little flair to my seeders :) Only the text in the 2nd arg is affected, so you can echo something else out on the same line with the default console color afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Your command is the entry point of your application, not the services. It should handle input and output. Your services should be isolated, do not couple them to the console.

For example, if you need to change your application to work in a different way - instead of outputting to the console, it will have to write to a database. Or, instead of running through the CLI, it should return a JSON with the aggregated messages. You will have to change each and every one of your services.

What I would do, is inject the services in the command, not the other way around. Then, let the command handle all of the output with its pretty colors.